# How to apply CSS to HTML page opened in jQuery dialog?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, css, jquery-dialog

I have an HTML page with all divs and CSS, that page is displayed in an ASPX page through a jQuery dialog. I have applied my CSS to the ASPX page and to the HTML page but the CSS is still not being applied.

I have the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function () {
        $('#Dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false, width: 800, height: 600, modal: true            
        });
    });


    $('.mosaic-overlay').live('click', function (e) {
        var url = $(this).attr('href');

        alert(url);

        $('#Dialog').html('').dialog('open').load(url);

        //        .load(url);
        e.preventDefault();
    });
</script>
```

How can I apply CSS to my HTML page dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

You could have your css already loaded on the page.
Calling [load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) loads the content and sets this as the innerHtml of the element.
All css rules on your page would be applied.

Alternatively, the required CSS could be part of the html that you load from the url.
These CSS rules would be created and applied before your content is displayed.
This method would be slower than having the CSS in your page already.

Comment: I tried to add stylesheet on the header of html page but still it doesnt load the page with css when opened on jquery dialog.

Answer (score 0):

To set css dynamically, JQuery has a css method - see here...

http://api.jquery.com/css/